# Counts based on conditions involving different tables

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

Using SQL Server 2012. Trying to get counts based on employee id for two different workflows/conditions. Ultimately, would like to have three columns; EmpID, Count Method 1, Count Method 2. Have tried several subqueries, but I'm stuck.

[Sample Data Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E6pU5.png)

```
-- Returns count for workflow 1
select 
    s.id [Employee ID], count(r.requisitionnumber)[Method 1] 
from 
    requisition r
left outer join 
    staff s on r.placerkey = s.staffkey
left outer join 
    location l on r.placerSignedInLocationKey = l.locationkey
group by 
    s.id

-- Returns count for workflow 2
select distinct 
    s.id [Employee ID], count(distinct(r.requisitionnumber) [Method 2]
from 
    requisition r
left outer join 
    orderedpanel op on r.requisitionkey = op.requisitionkey
left outer join 
    staff s on s.staffkey = op.staffkeyreleasedorderchoices 
            and staffKeyReleasedOrderChoices > 1
group by 
    s.id
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: Sorry Gordon, I should have included that previously. I've linked desired output and sample data (having trouble formatting as text).  Caramiriel did provide a suggestion that worked.  Always open to other suggestions, though.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always wire up two different queries using a join:

```
select 
    [Employee ID],
    [Method 1],
    [Method 2]
from (
    --Gives count for workflow 1
    select s.id [Employee ID], count(r.requisitionnumber)[Method 1] 
    from requisition r
    left outer join staff s
    on r.placerkey=s.staffkey
    left outer join location l on r.placerSignedInLocationKey=l.locationkey
    group by s.id
) workflow1
inner join (
    --Gives count for workflow 2
    select distinct s.id [Employee ID],count(distinct(r.requisitionnumber)  [Method 2]
    from requisition r
    left outer join orderedpanel op
    on r.requisitionkey=op.requisitionkey
    left outer join staff s on s.staffkey=op.staffkeyreleasedorderchoices
    where staffKeyReleasedOrderChoices >1
    group by s.id
) workflow2 on workflow1.[Employee ID] = workflow2.[Employee ID]
```

Comment: Note that I'm using `inner join` here. If one of the tables doesn't contain the employee, use another type of join.

Comment: Perfect.  I just had to change to an outer join, as some employees only use one of the workflows and others use both. Thanks for the assistance.